# How to extract digits in shell and assign into variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

`echo DEN_ML2.3_R02.zip | grep -o '[0-9]\+'`

```
Output: 

2
3  
02
```

I want to grep  `2.3` and `02` from `DEN_ML2.3_R02.zip` and assign to variables

Comment: Unclear how the solution should generalize. If you have only one single instance, then set `x=2.3` and `y=02`, and that's it.

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. Please see the relevant help-center article

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo DEN_ML2.3_R02.zip | grep -Eo '\-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?'
                                              _________ _
                                                ^       ^
                                             group    quantifier
```

The quantifier `?` means the group is *optional*

#### Output :

```
2.3
02
```

---

#### Assign to variables requirement :

```
$ read a1 a2 < <(echo $(grep -Eo '\-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?' <<< "DEN_ML2.3_R02.zip"))
```

or

```
$ read a1 a2 < <(
    grep -Eo '\-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?' <<< "DEN_ML2.3_R02.zip" |
    tr '\n' ' '
)
```

#### Result :

```
$ echo $a1
2.3
$ echo $a2
02
```